# What is this tactic called?

Tags: tactics, attack, patterns

```
[FEN "6k1/rp3ppq/p2p4/1p1Pr1nQ/1P2P3/4R1N1/P1B2P2/4R1K1 b - - 0 1"]

1... Nh3+ 2. Qxh3 (2. Kh2 Rxh5) 2... Qxh3
```

Black to move.

After Nh3+ white can move the king or take with the queen. Either way black can win the queen.

How is this tactic called?

Comment: Like Accumulation uses the phrase “could also be considered” in their answer, more complicated tactics often include multiple named themes which can overlap or confuse each other. One that I would see in this tactic but hasn’t been named so far is “X-ray defence” of the knight by the queen (the white queen defends the knight _through_ the black queen).

Comment: I think you mixed up the colors in the last sentence, or didnt you?

Comment: Ah yes – whoops!

Comment: @11684 i believe it's x-ray attack. see my answer.

Comment: user2664856, no offense to @Acccumulation but i think my answer is the 1 that should be accepted in re x-ray attack

Comment: @BCLC the attack on the queen is a direct attack, not an x-ray attack. The knight is defended through the queen (so that is an x-ray defence). Which piece would be attacked through which other piece, constituting an X-Ray attack according to you? Regarding your second comment: obviously most answerers are of the opinion that their answer is the best/should be accepted, why else write it?

Comment: @11684 i think based on chesstempo's definition this is an x-ray attack. am i wrong? https://chesstempo.com/tactical-motifs#X-Ray%20Attack

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a **discovered attack** with check (the rook attacking the queen is the discovered attack, the check is the discovering move). As the discovering move is also an attack, this gives rise to a **double attack**. The check must be answered, so the queen takes the knight even though it is protected. This could also be considered a [**desperado**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desperado_(chess)) from White's point of view; the queen can't be saved, so White might as well take the knight.

Comment: I chose this answer, because its the most beginner friendly one. Which suits the question best. Maybe you could add some bold formatting, like @Annatar? Then it would be even better.

Comment: But would you rather have a rook for the queen, or just the knight?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy It's the knight that is delivering the check. Taking the rook would be good (and taking the queen would be even better), except that it doesn't remove the check, and therefore isn't a legal move.

Comment: Yes, but in the 2. Kh2 Rxh5 scenario, 3. Nxh5 trades a queen for a rook. the knights likely get traded off as well 3. ... Qxh5 4. Rxh3

Answer (score 15):

It's not uncommon that a tactical sequence makes use of more than one general pattern.

Here, we have a **double attack** where one of these attacks is a **discovered** one (the rook on the queen) and the other is a **decoy** (the knight check lures the queen to a square where it will be undefended).

Comment: Agreed - as well, 'decoy' is sometimes called 'attraction'.

Answer (score 9):

I think it is a discovered attack. Normally at a discovered attack, you do give a check to the king, eventually a double check. Here what is different is that you do a check to the king but you discover an attack on the queen, not also towards the king.

Comment: *Here what is different is that you do a check to the king but you discover an attack on the queen, not also towards the king.* It's still a discovered attack - checking the king with the piece that is moving is common, because it forces a response and stops the attacked piece from moving away.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm going to refer to [chesstempo](https://chesstempo.com/tactical-motifs).)

I don't think there's just 1 tactic here. As other answers have pointed out, besides [discovery](https://chesstempo.com/tactical-motifs#Discovery) ([discoverer checks](https://chesstempo.com/tactical-motifs#Discoverer%20Checks)), there's also [double attack](https://chesstempo.com/tactical-motifs#Double%20Attack) or [desperado](https://chesstempo.com/tactical-motifs#Desperado). (i don't think it falls under chesstempo's desperado though. i think it's more of [trapped piece](https://chesstempo.com/tactical-motifs#Trapped%20Piece) than desperado, but I don't think it's even trapped piece.)

Something else I notice is [x-ray](https://chesstempo.com/tactical-motifs#X-Ray): As for [X-Ray Attack](https://chesstempo.com/tactical-motifs#X-Ray%20Attack) or [X-Ray Defense](https://chesstempo.com/tactical-motifs#X-Ray%20Defense), I believe this is [X-Ray Attack](https://chesstempo.com/tactical-motifs#X-Ray%20Attack)